# bind DateTime to CalendarColumn in DataGridview from datasource

Tags: c#, datagridview

With this piece of code ([partial pickup from C# corner)](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/11558/):

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Columns.Add("Select", typeof(bool));
 dt.Columns.Add("Employee No");
 dt.Columns.Add("Employee Name");
 dt.Columns.Add("Join Date", typeof(DateTime));
 DataRow dr;
 for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
 {
   dr = dt.NewRow();
   dr["Select"] = false;
   dr["Employee No"] = 1000 + i;
   dr["Employee Name"] = "Employee " + i;
   dr["Join Date"] = DateTime.Now;
   dt.Rows.Add(dr);
 }
 dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

`dataGridView1` will show checkbox at first column following by textboxes in others.

I want to bind  [CalendarColumn class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx) *(from MSDN)* with my DateTime. How is it suitable ?

**EDIT 1**

[from DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns Property MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx)

> When **AutoGenerateColumns** is set to **true**, the **DataGridView** control generates one column for each public property of the objects in the data source. If the bound objects implement the **ICustomTypeDescriptor** interface, the control generates one column for each property returned by the **GetProperties** method. Each column header will contain the value of the property name the column represents.

So `AutoGenerateColumns` links data type to visual representation. Looks something to do with. But how ?

**EDIT 2**

[Column Types in the DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxt3k60s.aspx) looks useful as well...

Comment: What is your question ? Did you add the Calender Column to the grid and set the `DataPropertyName` ?

Comment: "Did you add the Calender Column to the grid" not at all. Like I didn't add any `CheckboxColumn`. But `bool` is bound with `CheckboxColumn` automatically. I want the same with `DateTime` and `CalendarColumn`.

Comment: `DataPropertyName` looks far from what I want. Maybe *to bind* is not correct *to link* is better...